# Can't take file from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I use Asp.Net WebApi and jQuery.
From page to WebApi i send 'POST' HTTP-Request with object.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "api/Result",
  data: JSON.stringify(makeResultInfo()),//makeResultInfo - function that returns object
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  processData: true,
  success: function (data) {
    window.location = data;
    alert("success");
  },
  error: function (xhr) {
    alert('error');
  }
});
```

WebApi take object correctly and return Excel-file.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]ResultInfo value)
{
   ExcelClass ec = new ExcelClass();
   var stream = ec.GetStream(ec.mini_wb);//после теста поправить
   // processing the stream.
   var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
   {
      Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray())
   };
   result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
      new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
   {
      FileName = "test.xlsx"
   };
   result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
      new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
   return result;
   }
```

When i make Request to 'api/Result' without parameters - file downloading correctly. But when i send object, response incorrect always and alert always write 'error'.

How i can send object and take file in browser?

Comment: What error are you getting? If your'e not sure, open your Network tab, and click on the request that's failing. The response should give you details about the error.

Comment: My best guess is that you're getting an error in the parsing of the JSON that you are sending. Please check the browser console to see what error is being returned by the server. Could you include an example of the JSON formed by `makeResultInfo` and include the C# `ResultInfo` class?

Comment: When i write this code as HttpGet - all work.

Comment: I feel like the issue has to be somewhere along the lines of your parameter type. You're passing a string but the function is expecting a SQL Result `ResultInfo`. Can't say I've seen that before, but you might have to take the parameter as a string and convert it to the type you want *inside* the method. @JackA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.multiserverconnection.resultinfo.aspx

Comment: @JackA. post-method take object normaly, normaly parse and use. Also i can download file, but file returns only when i using links as `window.location = '/api/Result';`

Comment: @Santi `ResultInfo` it's my custom class, it's not a part of  `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.MultiServerConnection`

Comment: It would be useful to show the actual value you are passing in the POST request, and the structure of the ResultInfo class. It could be a mismatch between those. Also, what is the exact error you are getting back from the server? That's likely to give a big clue. (You can check it in the network tab of the browser, and (in some browsers) also in the console. Or you can rewrite your "error" callback to actually report the error and not just a generic message.).

Comment: @ADyson No problem with `ResultInfo`, no problem with response, because when i write `window.location = '/api/Result'` - file downloading.

Comment: but when you write `window.location = '/api/Result'` you aren't passing any ResultInfo object, so I don't see how that proves anything. The most obvious difference between that and your ajax version is that you're passing whatever the output of `makeResultInfo()` is to the server. So, I'll repeat, please show 1) the output of `makeResultInfo()`, 2) the structure of the C# ResultInfo class, and 3) the actual HTTP status code, error message, and any data in the response body from the ajax request.

Comment: @ADyson `ResultInfo` sending correctly trust me. See on WebApi-code. I don't using `ResultInfo`, it's test code. ExcelClass have some constructors:
`public ExcelClass()`//for tests
`public ExcelClass(ResultInfo ri)`//for this Application
`public ExcelClass(DataTable dt)`//for Other Application

Comment: "I don't using ResultInfo". What is `public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]ResultInfo value)` then? And what is `data: JSON.stringify(makeResultInfo())`? You _are_ using it, and it's very likely to be the problem, since that's the main difference between your "working" and "not working" scenarios. You might not use it afterwards within the method but that's not relevant to the _request_. I am trying to help you, but if you won't answer those simple questions then I can't. The **first** thing you should do when asking a question like this is show the actual error message, at the very least.

Comment: You're saying that `ResultInfo` isn't the problem, but then also telling us that the only difference between it *working* and *not working* is when you include the `ResultInfo` parameter...

Comment: @ADyson look screenshotes. I haven't problem with objects. [https://yadi.sk/d/cInJJcwP3JFmi2]

Comment: @Santi look screenshotes. I haven't problem with objects. [yadi.sk/d/cInJJcwP3JFmi2]

Comment: Those screenshots don't prove anything. They're all successful requests you made *by not passing any data from your JavaScript*, is that correct? Again, what we need to see is **the output of MakeResultInfo()** and the structure of your **ResultInfo** C# class.

Comment: the screenshot link returns "Nothing found" to me. Anyway, Santi is right, and is asking you for what I asked for 3 hours ago. I'll ask you one more time to provide the relevant 3 items of information I previously requested.  1) the output of makeResultInfo(), 2) the structure of the C# ResultInfo class, and 3) the actual HTTP status code, error message, and any data in the response body from the ajax request. I don't understand why you haven't done so already. Perhaps you don't really want to solve your problem. If you can't/won't provide the info then nobody can help you. It's your decision.